# How can I limit a cookie to "/admin" on my domain?

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookie-path

How can I make the cookie `session.cookie_path` only available for the module `"/admin/"`?

Zend Framework Code:

```
// Se Login?
public static function isLoggedIn() {
    $namespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth');
    $namespace->setExpirationSeconds(60*5); //5 Minutos dura una session

    $namespace->cookie_path = '/admin/'

    return Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity();
}
```

I can't get PHPSESSION to have the path set to `'/admin/'`. PHPSESSION always has the path set to `'/'` in the cookie. ;-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typeoneerror is almost there.  You're gonna want to use the setting "cookie_path" and not "cookie_domain"

Example:

```
    Zend_Session::setOptions(array(
        'cookie_lifetime' => 0,
        'cookie_path'     => "/admin",
        'cookie_domain'   => ".test.com",
        'cookie_secure'   => false,
        'cookie_httponly' => true
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to limit the cookie to "/admin" on the domain? you need to pass cookie_path as options to Zend_Session, not its _Namespace partner:

```
$settings = array("cookie_domain" => "/admin");
Zend_Session::setOptions($settings);
```

You can also start a session with a settings object:

```
Zend_Session::start($settings);
```

You could also store your settings in a config file:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('config.ini', 'development');
Zend_Session::setOptions($config->toArray());
```